# SQL: Bulk load data conversion error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy, mysqlimport

I am importing a text file into SQL using bulk insert.
Field delimiter is ^
row delimiter - \n
I am getting below error for some columns.

"Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 4, column 19 (PrimaryObjective)."

I have the below text in that column .
"Aim 1. To determine the effects of Product on cognition. We hypothesize that early treatment with Product for MS will delay or reverse cognitive dysfunction. We will test this by following SDMT scores in patients with RRMS who have received early versus delayed treatment with Product These results will further support the role of Product in protecting cognitive function in MS. Furthermore, these results will help establish a standard upon which to validate the new potential surrogate biomarkers"

Below one is the bulk insert query that I am using .

```
 EXEC ('
    BULK
    INSERT Vest_Base_Encounter
    FROM '''+@Vest_Base_Encounter_File+'''
    WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ''^'',
    ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
    FIRSTROW=1
    )')
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: There may be some kind of odd character in the text file at that point, which won't show up here after it's been copied and pasted into a question. Can you examine the file at that point in a good text editor and see if you can spot anything amiss? And what's the type (including character set) of the column?

Comment: I just checked the txt file. there is no odd characters in the file.
data type - [ntext]

Comment: I'm not sure there's much more we can suggest without actually seeing the file itself (or at least a line from it that reproduces the problem, as an actual file rather than a cut & paste.)